# Cannot access interface which is a supertype of another interface error only for Java not for Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I have two libraries, one depending upon the other.

Lib 1 - Lib1.java:

```
package com.example.lib1;

public interface Lib1 {
}
```

Lib 2 - Lib2.java with dependency `implementation "com.example:lib1:1.0.0"`

```
package com.example.lib2;

import com.example.lib1.Lib1;

public interface Lib2 extends Lib1 {
    String hello = "Hello";
}
```

Then have an app using Lib 2. Here this Java class compiles fine

```
package com.example.libtest;

import com.example.lib2.Lib2;

public class TestJava {
    public String hello = Lib2.hello;
}
```

But with the kotlin class I get an error

```
package com.example.libtest

import com.example.lib2.Lib2

fun test() {
    val x = Lib2.hello; <-- error here
}
```

`Cannot access 'com.example.lib1.Lib1' which is a supertype of 'com.example.lib2.Lib2'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies`.

If I use `api` instead of `implementation` in lib2 gradle file, the Kotlin file compiles too.

Two questions:

1. I understand `api` exposes transitive dependencies but when `implementation` is used why Java class compiles fine while Kotlin errors out?
2. Should `api` be needed here at all? The library `lib1` should be hidden from the app anyway?

I am using Java 11, AGP 7.3.1, Gradle 7.4. Kotlin (only used in the app - 1.7.20).